# Para que serve o AppSettings?

Tags: .net, configuração, web.config, app.config

Eu estava dando uma olhada no Web.confg e gostaria de saber para que serve o `<appSettings>`? No que ele interfere em nossa aplicação?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Contém configurações de aplicativo personalizadas. Essa é uma seção de configuração predefinidos fornecida pelo .NET Framework.

## Sintaxe

```
<appSettings>
  <!-- Elements to add, clear, or remove configuration settings -->
</appSettings>
```

## Comentários

O  elemento armazena informações de configuração de aplicativo personalizado, como cadeias de conexão de banco de dados, caminhos de arquivo, URLs de serviço Web XML ou qualquer outra informação de configuração personalizada para um aplicativo. Os pares chave/valor especificados na  elemento são acessadas em código usando o ConfigurationSettings classe.

Você pode usar o arquivo atributo na  elemento do Web. config e arquivos de configuração do aplicativo. Esse atributo especifica um arquivo de configuração que fornece configurações adicionais ou substitui as configurações especificadas na  elemento. O arquivo atributo pode ser usado no código-fonte controle equipe cenários de desenvolvimento, como quando um usuário deseja substituir as configurações de projeto especificadas em um arquivo de configuração do aplicativo.
Arquivos de configuração especificados pelo arquivo atributo deve ter um nó raiz do  vez .

## Exemplo

O exemplo a seguir mostra um arquivo de configurações de aplicativo externo (custom.config) que define uma configuração de aplicativo personalizada:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<appSettings>
  <add key="MyCustomSetting" value="MyCustomSettingValue" />
</appSettings>
```

O exemplo a seguir mostra um arquivo de configuração de aplicativo que consome a configuração no arquivo de configurações externas e define sua própria configuração de aplicativo:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings file="custom.config">
    <add key="ApplicationName" value="MyApplication" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

## arquivo de configuração

Esse elemento pode ser usado no arquivo de configuração do aplicativo, arquivo de configuração de máquina (Machine. config), e Web. config arquivos que não estão no nível de diretório do aplicativo.

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/appsettings/appsettings-element-for-configuration)

Answer (score 4):

A tag `<appSettings/>` serve como container para as configurações especificas de sua aplicação, no caso, as configurações que o desenvolvedor quiser armazenar.

Exemplo:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="conf1" value="teste"/>
<appSettings/>
```

Note que acrescentamos na tag `<appSettings/>` uma tag filha, que corresponde a nossa configuração. Os atributos de `<add/>` usados foram `key` e `value`, sendo que `key` define o nome da configuração e `value` o valor que ela armazena.

Fonte: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/1612/net-entendendo-o-arquivo-webconfig.aspx#ixzz5eqkibPuq

Answer (score 4):

No appSettings podemos criar chaves e definir valores para essas chaves e, o que eu acho muito bom, não precisamos recompilar a aplicação para trocar o valor dessas chaves.

Vamos para dois exemplos de onde usar a appSettings:

1- Vamos supor que logo após a homologação do projeto, seu cliente, decidiu trocar o e-mail no qual ele recebe quando a aplicação envia. Ao invés de ir procurar a variável que guardamos o e-mail dele e trocar pelo novo, na appSettings trocamos para o novo e-mail e pronto.

2- "- Que bacana João, olha essa condição, se item == 45. Porque 45???". Claro que não vamos colocar tudo no appSettings, mas seria bem melhor entender se a condição fosse, se item == appSettings["codCarro"]. Um exemplo básico!

Está explicado... Agora mãos a obra!

Vamos na nossa Web.Config criar nossas chaves. É extremamente simples:

exemplo:
http://www.morcegosweb.com/morcegos/arquivos/lightbox/app1.jpg

Leia mais aqui para você entender melhor: http://www.linhadecodigo.com.br/artigo/2209/definicoes-da-aplicacao-appsettings.aspx#ixzz5eqlRvG48